# ¿Cómo sumo el valor de dos horas distinas en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un reloj checador, sin embargo, necesito sumar el valor de dos lapsos de horas que tengo guardados en dos variables respectivamente para que me dé el número total de horas trabajadas en un día, sin embargo, hasta el momento no he podido. A continuación dejo el código que uso:

```
$horaLlegada = new DateTime($reg['horaLlegada']);
        $comidaSalida = new DateTime($reg['comidaSalida']);
        $intervalo = $horaLlegada -> diff($comidaSalida);

$comidaLlegada = new DateTime($reg['comidaLlegada']);
            $horaSalida = new DateTime($reg['horaSalida']);
            $intervalo2 = $horaSalida -> diff($comidaLlegada);
```

Quiero sumar los valores de las variables $intervalo e $intervalo2

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es sumar dos horas, quizás este fragmento de código te pueda ayudar. Hay que transformar la hora en formato `HH:mm:ss` a `segundos`. Intenta lo siguiente:

```
// Separamos el tiempo en un array para pasarlo a segundos
function explode_tiempo($tiempo) {
    $arr_tiempo = explode(':', $tiempo);
    $segundos = $arr_tiempo[0] * 3600 + $arr_tiempo[1] * 60 + $arr_tiempo[2];
    return $segundos;
}

// Transformar los segundos en hora formato HH:mm:ss
function segundos_hhmm($seg) {
    $horas = floor($seg / 3600);
    $minutos = floor($seg / 60 % 60);
    $segundos = floor($seg % 60);

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $horas, $minutos, $segundos);
}

$hora1 = "03:00:15";
$hora2 = "02:25:15";

$h1 = explode_tiempo($hora1);
$h2 = explode_tiempo($hora2);

$total_tiempo_segundos = $h1 + $h2;

echo segundos_hhmm($total_tiempo_segundos);
```

Espero que te sea de tu ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No especificas el formato de entrada. Suponiendo que los datos de entrada tienen formato `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`, usando un array de test:

```
$reg = array(
'horaLlegada'=>'2019-07-20 08:01:32', 
'comidaSalida'=>'2019-07-20 12:03:15', 
'comidaLlegada'=>'2019-07-20 12:58:23', 
'horaSalida'=>'2019-07-20 17:02:38');
```

Se pueden hacer los cálculos de la siguiente forma

```
<?php
$intervalo1 = strtotime($reg['comidaSalida']) - strtotime($reg['horaLlegada']);
$intervalo2 = strtotime($reg['horaSalida']) - strtotime($reg['comidaLlegada']);
// ####
echo $intervalo1 . ' segundos' . PHP_EOL; // Segundos
echo $intervalo2 / 3600 . ' horas'. PHP_EOL; // Horas
echo 'Tiempo total: '. ($intervalo1 + $intervalo2)/3600 . ' horas' . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Tiempo total Formateado: '. gmdate('H:i:s', $intervalo1 + $intervalo2);
```

Salida

> ```
> 14503 segundos
> 4.0708333333333 horas
> Tiempo total: 8.0994444444444 horas
> Tiempo total Formateado: 08:05:58
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Desgraciadamente la clase [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) no provee un metodo para sumar objetos DateInterval. Para poder hacer el cálculo podemos crear un nuevo objeto [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) y añadirle los dos DateInterval o los que necesitemos y despues calcular la diferencia con su valor de inicio. Ejemplo:

```
<?php
// array de ejemplo con datos
$reg = array(
'horaLlegada'  =>'2019-07-20 08:01:32', 
'comidaSalida' =>'2019-07-20 12:03:15', 
'comidaLlegada'=>'2019-07-20 12:58:23', 
'horaSalida'   =>'2019-07-20 17:02:38');

// esto casi igual que esta, solo forzamos para que el valor sea siempre positivo
$horaLlegada = new DateTime($reg['horaLlegada']);
$comidaSalida = new DateTime($reg['comidaSalida']);
// aqui forzamos con true como 2º parametro
$intervalo = $horaLlegada->diff($comidaSalida, true);

$comidaLlegada = new DateTime($reg['comidaLlegada']);
$horaSalida = new DateTime($reg['horaSalida']);
// aqui forzamos con true como 2º parametro
$intervalo2 = $comidaLlegada->diff($horaSalida, true);

// aqui hacemos la suma

// Creamos un nuevo objeto DateTime para hacer el calculo
// puedes utilizar cualquiere hora
$total = new DateTime($reg['horaLlegada']);
// clonamos para utilizarlo despues
$base_time = clone $total;


// añadimos los intervalos que necesitemos
$total->add($intervalo);
$total->add($intervalo2);

// Calculamos la diferencia con el valor inicial
$total_tiempo_trancurrido = $base_time->diff($total);

print_r($total_tiempo_trancurrido->format('Ha trascurrido %H h %I min %S seg'));
// RESULTADO: Ha trascurrido 08 h 05 min 58 seg
?>
```

Otra opción quizas mas elegante es crear una clase que extienda de DateInterval y añadir un nuevo método para que sume los periodos. Ejemplo:

```
<?php
//Creamos la clase
class MyDateInterval extends DateInterval
{
    public function __construct() {
        // inicializamos la clase con un periodo vacio
        parent::__construct('PT0S');
    }
    public function add(DateInterval $interval)
    {
        foreach (str_split('ymdhis') as $prop) {
            $this->$prop += $interval->$prop;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}

// nuestros datos 
$reg = array(
    'horaLlegada'   =>'2019-07-20 08:01:32', 
    'comidaSalida'  =>'2019-07-20 12:03:15', 
    'comidaLlegada' =>'2019-07-20 12:58:23', 
    'horaSalida'    =>'2019-07-20 17:02:38'
);
// periodo 1
$horaLlegada  = new DateTime($reg['horaLlegada']);
$comidaSalida = new DateTime($reg['comidaSalida']);
$intervalo    = $horaLlegada->diff($comidaSalida, true);
// periodo 2
$comidaLlegada = new DateTime($reg['comidaLlegada']);
$horaSalida    = new DateTime($reg['horaSalida']);
$intervalo2    = $comidaLlegada->diff($horaSalida);

// Inicializamos un objeto de la clase MyDateInterval que hemos creado
$time = new MyDateInterval;
// y añadimos los intervalos DateInterval
$time->add($intervalo);
$time->add($intervalo2);
// Mostramos el resultado 
echo $time->format('Ha trascurrido %H h %I min %S seg');
// RESULTADO: Ha trascurrido 08 h 05 min 58 seg

// podemos tambien utilzar encadenamiento ya que en el metodo add retornamos $this
// de esta forma podemos acortar codigo
// Inicializamos un objeto de la clase MyDateInterval que hemos creado
$time = new MyDateInterval;
echo $time->add($intervalo)->add($intervalo2)->format('Ha trascurrido %H h %I min %S seg');
// RESULTADO: Ha trascurrido 08 h 05 min 58 seg
```

Documentación:

- [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)
- [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php)
- [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)
- [DateInterval::format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php)